# Add Azure APIM Users & subscriptions programmatically from My Asp.Net Core Blazor website

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-api-management, blazor-webassembly

I want to add Azure APIM users & Subscription from my website instead azure portal.
and want to show subscription keys in my website...

Is there any library or something available for that ??? It is possible ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might be able to do it via the management APIs of APIM. Here is the API for managing User: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/user, and Subscription: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/subscription.